# Moderator view for "total posts flagged" shows a large (incorrect?) number

Tags: bug, flags, moderator-tools

In addition to all my other super-secret moderator tools, (ie, knowing when you're sleeping, knowing when you're awake, knowing when you're bad or good, seeing you when you're showering, etc) I have the ability to see the number of posts that a particular user has that have been flagged.

This shows up in people's profiles next to the "mod" button, here's mine:

[image]

If I click through, I can see the posts of mine that have been flagged, and I count a total of 3.  I am bad at math, but I *think* 3 is significantly less than 46.

I know recently flag counts were adjusted to include comment flags, but as a moderator I think I'd notice if I was flagged for comments 43 times or so.

I checked a few other users and noticed similar discrepencies.  For instance, badp is bad to the bone and has 90+ in his count, although the list shows 9 (and it's paginated, although the second page is blank)

Comment: Fellow moderator [Oak](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/flagged-posts/122) also has a count of 70, and his list shows 5.  Again, there's a second page to the list, and it's blank.

Comment: This has been an issue with MSO for quite some time now. Has it just manifested on your site?

Comment: I show 8 but really have 3. I don't recall this occurring before on UX